# What data should be used to train an ensemble of pre-trained models?

Tags: training, ensemble-modeling

I split my dataset into train and test data. Then I trained logistic regression, SVM, and random forest models using pipelines with cross-validation and train data.

I saved best-performing models with tuned parameters via best_estimator_

And now I want to make a voting ensemble with these models to predict using test data.

The questions are:

- Can pre-trained models be used in ensembles this way?
- On which data I should train the ensemble?